# Recover Network Password by Tricking Device into Connecting to Ad Hoc with Same Name

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, ad-hoc-network

My friend has lost his network login information on all of his devices except his iPad, and does not have access to his router to change it. I have an idea to recover it using an ad hoc network with the same SSID. From what I understand, it is possible for hackers to capture packets not intended for them by creating an identical SSID. If this is correct, could I perhaps trick the iPad in to thinking that the ad hoc network is the actual network, and when it attempts to connect with the password, capture it in a plaintext format?

Comment: Well, assuming what you would get by sniffing is a hash and not the plaintext password then I think your "friend" would just be better off getting to the physical router and holding the reset button for 30 seconds to restore it to factory defaults.  And if you have physical access then you *always* have root access if you know what you're doing.

Comment: Try on a Windows device [WirelessKeyView v1.72 - Recover lost wireless network key](http://nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_key.html)

Comment: @headkase I detect a sense of doubt about the existence of my friend. :) Nonetheless, he does not have physical access to the router.

Comment: @DavidPostill Doesn't this program only recover information from the computer? If so, then it cannot be used for the issue at hand.

Comment: You didn't mention what his other devices were ... ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill His other device is a computer running Windows, but the computer in question does not have the WiFi information on it. The only device that he owns that he can currently use to connect to the internet is his iPad. The computer running Windows is the reason he needs the password, as he obviously wants to connect it.

Comment: @DavidB Regardless of your "friends" existence, ;), you could go get a Linux distribution that is designed specifically for penetration testing such as Black Arch.  The problem is that you could spend a week learning the basics or you could, like, phone up someone who does have access to the router and get them to hold the button for 30 seconds.